# Behat: How to test classes with dependencies?

Tags: php, dependencies, behat

In the Behat [documentation](http://behat.org/en/latest/quick_start.html#automating-steps), we get a simple example with `shelf` and `basket` classes:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->shelf = new Shelf();
    $this->basket = new Basket($this->shelf);
}
```

But in a real world application, it will hardly be that simple. In the application itself, I would use a dependency injection container to resolve dependencies automatically. How would this be achieved in a Behat `FeatureContext` class - by mocking dependencies?

Comment: If you are using Symfony there is an extension for that, if not, you can write your own extension to inject either the container or the dependencies. Check both symfony2 extension and behatch contexts for a reference.

Comment: Check also this extension: https://github.com/jakzal/BehatNoExtension

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Symfony, but isn't there a lot of overhead to load the whole Kernel just to have dependency injection available? Still, interesting.